# How can I measure page views (PVs) of a child page within an iframe using GA4?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am tracking page views (PVs) using GA4.
I have an iframe embedded in the parent page for the child page, but I cannot measure the PVs of the child page.

When checking with GTM's preview, the GA4 tag of the child page seems to be firing, but it appears that the Page view event is not firing.

How can I trigger the Page view event even in the page within the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

In GTM, where you have defined Tag Configuration, make sure you have activated the trigger for **All Pages** (by default it has the type equal to Page View)
[image: photo1]